# Mapping Antarctic Polar Stereographic data in ipyleaflet

Tags: python, leaflet, jupyter, ipyleaflet

I am trying to plot Antarctic Sea-Ice EPSG:3031 data using ipyleaflet like so:

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, WMSLayer, basemaps

wms = WMSLayer(
    url='http://geos.polarview.aq/geoserver/wms',
    layers='polarview:iceedgeS15',
    format='image/png',
    transparent=True,
    attribution='Polarview'
)

m = Map(basemap=basemaps.NASAGIBS.BlueMarble3031, center=(-90, 0), zoom=1, crs=projections.EPSG3031)

m.add_layer(wms)

m
```

The photos in the following links illustrate my issues clearly:

[The data and the basemap do not align](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvcEM.png)

If I omit the basemap and projection information it looks [reasonable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zguK.png)  in terms of alignment but doesn't have the perspective and projection I desire. I have been also been using [Leafmap](https://leafmap.org/) to add local geotiffs and run into similar issues.

I have read through a few relevant [PRs](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/issues/612) and checked out [xarray-leaflet](https://github.com/davidbrochart/xarray_leaflet/blob/main/examples/custom_projection.ipynb) but haven't had any luck. This [sea-ice concentration data](https://seaice.uni-bremen.de/data/amsr2/asi_daygrid_swath/s6250/2022/feb/Antarctic/asi-AMSR2-s6250-20220202-v5.4.tif) is an example of a non-wms data source that I encounter the same problem with which could be helpful for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.
You'll need to add coordinate reference system (CRS) information to your WMSLayer.  See the [custom projections notebook](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/blob/master/examples/CustomProjections.ipynb) within the ipyleaflet examples. For spatial projections that are not Web Mercator (EPSG:3857), you'll likely need to define the bounds of your imagery.

```
    from ipyleaflet import Map, WMSLayer, basemaps

    # create map with NASA Blue Marble as background
    m2 = Map(basemap=basemaps.NASAGIBS.BlueMarble3031,
         center=(-90, 0), zoom=1, crs=projections.EPSG3031)

    # projection for Polarview sea ice edge
    POLAR3031 = dict(
        name='EPSG:3031',
        custom=True,
        proj4def="""+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-71 +lon_0=0 +k=1
            +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs""",
        bounds=[[-2822131.5,-3057369.25],[3744213.75,3822194.25]]
    )
    wms = WMSLayer(
        url='http://geos.polarview.aq/geoserver/wms',
        layers='polarview:iceedgeS15',
        format='image/png',
        transparent=True,
        attribution='Polarview',
        crs=POLAR3031
    )
    m2.add(wms)

    # show map
    m2
```